# App/website blocker for S23 Ultra that cannot be removed

Tags: samsung, system-apps, android-13, productivity

I am using blocking apps to try and put as many barriers in place as possible to prevent me accessing gambling websites/Apps.

I have a Samsung galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13. I haven't been able to find an app without a workaround.

"AppBlock" is the best - until I discovered yesterday it can simply be uninstalled by entering safe mode. Is there a non-root way of disabling safe mode or making the app a system app so it can't be disabled/uninstalled in safe mode?

With "strict mode" activated AppBlock is great - I couldn't circumvent it. But booting into safe mode allows the changing of permissions subsequently allowing me to uninstall the app .

I tried a downloadable play store app to turn it into a system app but that didn't work.

Edit: at this point if it's possible to achieve this by rooting my device I will happily do so.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Everything you can put in place you can also remove, there's no way around it. You need professional help for the issue, not a technical "hack".

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes I agree. I have just been diagnosed with ADHD, and working with a therapist to curb my impulsive behaviour. But adding additional measures like blocks is, I've been advised, a great accompaniment to the professional help I'm now receiving. For example on my Mac I use cold turkey, to amazing effect. I just wish there was something similar for android. Thanks